# Is the autocomplete tag a valid tag in .shtml file?

Tags: html, notepad++, shtml

I was adding the autocomplete attribute to a few password input fields and I noticed that in notepad++ as my text editor the autocomplete = "off" attribute is valid in various types of files (i.e. html, xsl), but in .shtml files autocomplete = "off" is not recognized as a valid attribute.

By recognized,I mean it is not highlighted in red.

Is autocomplete a valid attribute in a .shtml file?

BTW: You can test this out by creating a new file in notepad ++ and adding this code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<input type="password" size="80" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off">

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Save as .xsl you will notice that the autocomplete attribute is in red, but if you save the save file as a .shtml file, then autocomplete will not be highlighted in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocomplete` is a tag is that is valid if you deliver your html document with a `html5` doctype.

The `suffix` of a document does not matter here. You can deliver a `html` document as a plain html document `.html`/`.htm`, created by some script `.php`, or without any suffix `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634257/is-the-autocomplete-tag-a-valid-tag-in-shtml-file`.

The important part is the `Content-Type`  and which `<!DOCTYPE`  is used.

The various editors detect the *programming language* of the document using the suffix and then loading some a matching *syntax-highlighter* and *validator*. As those *validators*/*syntax-highlighter* might be different for the different suffixes they might have different results. As of that the one use for `.shtml` might be outdated or might not be able to detect that you want to use `html5`.